# iPad: app with TabBarController not working

Tags: ipad, xamarin.ios, tabbar

I have an iPhone app that works just fine on the iPhone.  I am trying to get it to work on the iPad (v 1), but it won't move off the first view.

I have a TabBarController with 5 views.  When I tap on the other views, they don't show.  Is there something I need to do differently when using a TabBarController for the iPad?

BTW, it doesn't work on the similator either...

Answer (score 0):

I'm making an assumption here but if you originally designed it for the iPhone only and want to convert it to a universal app for both iPhone and iPad, you will need to have two MainWindow.xib files. One for the iPhone and another for the iPad. And you'll have to specify those .xib files in the project settings. Set the Main and iPad interface files. An easy way to get a version of the iPad MainWindow.xib is to create a new project for the iPad and just copy it over to your own proj.

[image: project settings]